# No almacena en base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

```html
<?php

include 'conexion_be.php';

$nombre_completo = $_POST['nombre_completo'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contraseña'];
$correo_electronico = $_POST['correo_electronico'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

$query = "INSERT INTO usuario(`nombre_completo`, `contraseña`, `correo_electronico`, `telefono`)
          VALUES('nombre_completo','contraseña','correo_electronico','telefono')";
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

Estoy realizando un formulario `html` con registro a base de datos al registrar aparece el mensaje de registro exitoso pero no almacena los datos en la tabla. Ya revise el `method post` les muestro mi código ayuda por favor.

```html
        <div class="formulario">
            <h2>Crea tu Cuenta</h2>
            <form action="php/registro_usuario_be.php" method = "POST" class="formulario-login">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre completo" name="nombre_completo"required>
                
                <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="contraseña" required>
                
                <input type="email" placeholder="Correo Electronico" name="correo electronico"required>
                
                <input type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono"required>
                
                <button>"Registrarse"</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="reset-password">
            <a href="#">Olvide mi Contraseña?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ALLÍ SOLO VEO CODIGO HTML  y la conexion a la BD ? ,  y los submit y las querys en los botones de login, register, los insert en la columnas de nombre y password, aqui veo solo el esqueleto...

Comment: Agrega tu código PHP por favor

Comment: Muestra lo que haces en `registro_usuario_be.php` pulsando en [edit]. Si usas Ajax, muestra también el código de Ajax. Gracias.

Comment: En tu HTML tienes esto correo electronico con espacio y luego en tu PHP esperas esto correo_electronico unifo con guión bajo, prueba corregir eso y nos dices

Comment: BetaM gracias hice la correccion, pero sigue igual, no almacena en la tabla

Answer (score 2):

El error lo tienes en la query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuario(`nombre_completo`, `contraseña`, 
`correo_electronico`, `telefono`)
VALUES('nombre_completo','contraseña','correo_electronico','telefono')";
```

Si te fijas, en la seccion VALUES pones los literales `nombre_completo`, `contraseña`... en lugar de las variables que has definido antes.

Revisa la tabla usuario, y veras que cada vez que ejecutas te muestra una nueva linea con esos datos.

Tu consulta deberia ser:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuario(`nombre_completo`, `contraseña`, 
`correo_electronico`, `telefono`) VALUES('$nombre_completo','$contrasena','$correo_electronico','$telefono')";
```

fijate en los $ que aparecen delante de VALUES, esa es la diferencia. Ahora deberia añadir los datos que pones en el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías en tu archivo php reemplazar la ultima linea por esta

```
$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Con esto debería pintar el error por el que no esta registrando en la BD, con ese error podrías mostrarlo y podemos ayudarte mejor.